# What is the correct delimiter in this Java Scanner example?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a file with comma separated floating point numbers and CR LF at the end of each line. For testing, I'm using a short string as shown here:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner("0.1,0.2,0.3,\r\n0.4,0.5,0.6");

    s.useDelimiter(",|,\\r\\n");

    while(s.hasNext())
        System.out.println(s.next());
```

What is a correct delimiter to produce exactly 6 numeric tokens? The one shown above produces 7 tokens, including an empty one:

```
    0.1
    0.2
    0.3

    0.4
    0.5
    0.6
```

Comment: `,|,\\r\\n` means that comma will always be tried first. Try instead `,\\r\\n|,`

Comment: Technically this code produces 6 tokens one of them `\r\n0.4`

Comment: @defaultlocale You are right. The fourth token had EOL stuck to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`,|,\\r\\n` means that option 1 is `,`. If that isn't matched, try `,\\r\\n`. This means that the second option will never match, because if the match starts with a comma, option 1 will have already matched it.

Instead try `,\\r\\n|,`, first trying to match the sequence that has more than just a comma `,\\r\\n`. If that doesn't match, then try matching just the comma `,`.

Comment: In case you're not on Windows, doing expect newline to be `\r\n`. Better delimiter would be `",[\r\n]*"`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably `",\\s*"`.  This will treat a comma, followed by any number of whitespace characters, as a delimiter.  Since `\\r` and `\\n` are whitespace characters, it will work great on your input, and you don't have to worry about the order problems you get with `|`.  After seeing a `,`, the scanner will consume as many whitespace characters as it finds.

This means that the pattern will also match some things your original pattern didn't, such as multiple consecutive line breaks, spaces, tabs, etc.  In practice, this is probably what you want anyway.  If not, then you can go with Moishe's answer or `",(\\r\\n)?"` which matches `,` and then consumes one `"\\r\\n"` sequence if that comes next.

Comment: Agree. Yours is more general and elegant solution.